# Value of type 'Result<Image, AFError>' (aka 'Result Ullmage, AFError>') has no member

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, cocoapods

Estoy usando Alamofire version 5.4.4 con Swift 5 y Xcode 11.
Intentando de descargar una imagen desde internet me sale el siguiente error:
[image]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto y añade el valor de `urlImage` para saber qué estás enviando, además, aclara qué es lo que debes recibir en la respuesta; si mejoras la pregunta es posible ayudarte.

Comment: Pues eso. Intentas directamente llegarle a un atributo `value` que no está en `response.result`. Sin más info, eso es lo que podemos contarte.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres utilizar `response.result` deberás utilizar un código similar al siguiente:

```
AF.request (urlImage!).responseImage { response in
      switch response.result {
       case .success(let value):
          cell.myImage.image = value

       case .failure(let error):
          let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
          alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
          alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Esto es así por el [Result protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) al cual estas accediendo cuando escribes `response.result`, en este caso wrapper de Alamofire.

En caso de que no quieras utilzarlo podrías escribiar algo como:

```
AF.request (urlImage!).responseImage { response, error in
    if let data = response.data {
      cell.myImage. image = data
    } else {
   print("Aquí manejo los errores: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

PD: No es buena práctica hacer API calls desde tu ViewController –excepto que sea muy pequeño– intenta hacerlo desde otra clase. Ejmplo: ImageService.swift